# Algorithms for removing oscillations?

Tags: wavelet, time-frequency, denoising

I am interested in removing oscillations from a signal to capture the lower-frequency variations, similar to the objective of [this problem](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/9671/how-to-remove-the-periodic-oscillations-from-a-signal). The oscillations vary in frequency in the time domain, so wavelet shrinkage seems to be a reasonable option, but most of the literature on wavelet shrinkage is applied to denoising, where the noise to be shrunk is i.i.d. Gaussian. Low-frequency oscillations are generally autocorrelated.

Is it still technically sound to apply wavelet shrinkage for removing higher frequency components even though they are not noise? Is there a better method? I am not aware of too many spatially-adaptive low-pass filters which have a convenient interpretation as wavelets.

Below are examples of two of such signals. As you can see, the oscillations occur with different frequencies along the space/time domain (x-axis). I have tried Fourier smoothing, but it does not seem to leave any relevant features. (I have also tried truncated SVD, but it also does a horrible job removing the oscillations.)

[image]

Comment: What's wrong with using the answer suggested in the post you point to?  Jumping from there to wavelet shrinkage seems like a big leap.  Can you share something of how your data looks? Can you do some stock standard filtering to precondition the signal before adding more complexity?

Comment: @Peter, thanks for the suggestion. I have added a figure to further illustrate my problem.

Comment: Hey my friend, here some appreciations..... Somebody is asking you to put Wavelets, SVDs or Adaptive Low Pass Dynamic Non-linear Time-Varying Filters on the game?. Are you seeking for techniques for your PhD or Master Paper/Thesiswork, or is a problem you need readily solved?. Which features do you want to capture? Did you tried `smooth` or `butter` first than any other? Did you tried an `spectrogram`? Did you tried standard low pass filters? Did you tried the filter on the derivative?..... Answer me that for clarifying where to point this.....